# Porque el bucle se queda pegado ,python recien inicie a aprender

Tags: while

[Gente necesito ayuda]

menu = 2

titulo2 = "Inicia el combate"

turno = 1

```
while menu == 2: 
                                                                                  
    if turno_de_ataque == 1:  
        print(titulo2.center(90, "="))                                                                  
        print(f"\nTurno {turno}\n")
                                                                      
        print(f"Ataca {personaje_jugador1}")                                                        
        if personaje_jugador1 == "kayn":                                                            
            print("(1)Guadaña Giratoria: inflige 20 Daño\n")                                        
            print("(2)habilidad epecial: inflige 30 daño\n")
            ataque = int(input("Seleccion el numero que corresponde a la habilidad para atacar\n")) 
            break
```

[ deberia de entrar al while pero no se que esta mal con ese codigo ]

```
        if ataque == 1:                                                                             
            vida_jugador2 -= 20                                                                     
            print(f"{personaje_jugador2} Recibe un ataque (!) (!) (!)\n\n")                         
            print(f"La vida de {personaje_jugador2} es: {vida_jugador2}")                           
            turno += 1                                                                              
            break
```

[Aca deberia hacer el ataque el jugador 1]

```
        if ataque == 2:                                                                             
            vida_jugador2 -= 30                                                                     
            print(f"{personaje_jugador2} Recibe un ataque (!) (!) (!)\n\n")                         
            print(f"La vida de {personaje_jugador2} es : {vida_jugador2}")                          
            turno += 1                                                                              
            menu = 2
            break
```

```
    if turno_de_ataque == 2:                                                                        
    print(f"Ataca {personaje_jugador2}")
```

[si el turno de ataque es 2 ,inicia atacando el jugador 2]
break

Comment: pues no veo donde rompes el ciclo, tu condicion dice `menu==2` entonces entra al ciclo, pero como el valor de menu no cambia no logra salir.

Comment: el problema es que no entra XD,si entra deberia ejecutar el *if turno_de_ataque == 1:* y ahi ejecutar  el codigo de * if personaje_jugador1 == "kayn": * para que se impriman la habilidades del personaje     ahora ataque si es igual a 1 deberia hacer el rebajo a la vida , no se si me explico o estoy haciendo una mala interpretacion de lo mi codigo,que es lo mas probable

Comment: Te recomiendo que incluyas el código que te falta, al menos la asignación de las cuatro variables que te faltan, de las que una es indispesable para comenzar el bucle `while`: `turno_de_ataque`. Además, pon los comentarios dentro del código para no romper la visual y así seguirlo mejor, amén de ver la indentación...